# Semantic UI: How to cancel the addition of label in multi-select dropdown

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I have to check the value that is being selected and in some circumstances, not to allow the addition. I tried this but onAdd seams to fire before the actual addition:

```
$dependenciesDropdown.dropdown({
    onAdd: function(addedValue, addedText, $addedChoice){
        if(<some special case>){
            $dependenciesDropdown.dropdown('remove selected', addedValue);
        }
    }
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same problem as you've described. Instead, you can overwrite the select action to evaluate your special case and determine which options are allowed before they are added to the UI.

**Read more:** [Specifying select action](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#specifying-select-action)

**Example:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').dropdown({
    action: function(text, value) {
      if (value != '3') {
        $('select').dropdown('set selected', value);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select multiple="" class="ui dropdown">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three (disabled)</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks a lot. Have you reported the `onAdd` behavior as a bug?

Comment: Great stuff. I didn't experience it until it I started to answer this question.